# how do people deal with iterating a Swift struct value-type property?

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct, pass-by-value

Here's an obvious situation that must arise all the time for people:

```
struct Foundation {
    var columns : [Column] = [Column(), Column()]
}
struct Column : CustomStringConvertible {
    var cards = [Card]()
    var description : String {
        return String(describing:self.cards)
    }
}
struct Card {}
var f = Foundation()
for var c in f.columns {
    c.cards.append(Card())
}
```

That code is legal but of course it has no effect on `f`, because `var c` is still a copy — the actual `columns` of `f` are unaffected.

I am not having any difficulties understanding *why* that happens. My question is what people generally *do* about it.

Clearly I can just make the whole matter go away by declaring Column a **class** instead of a **struct**, but is that what people usually do? (I'm trying to follow a mental stricture that one should avoid classes when there's no need for dynamic dispatch / polymorphism / subclassing; maybe I'm carrying that too far, or maybe there's something else people usually do, like using `inout` somehow.)

Comment: Adding a "mutating each element" method has been discussed on the Swift forums (https://forums.swift.org/t/idea-mutatingforeach-for-collections/18442 & https://forums.swift.org/t/in-place-map-for-mutablecollection/11111). However I believe the eventual goal is to implement this at language level once we have a proper ownership model, [allowing you to say something like](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/decff7c700005a8af526736cc42f3960654998ae/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#mutating-iteration) `for inout c in f.columns`.

Comment: I don't know what people generally do. What I have seen as “workaround” is to iterate over the indices instead: `for i in f.columns.indices { f.columns[i].cards.append(Card()) }`

Comment: @MartinR That's quite a good compromise, would you like to give that as an answer?

Comment: @Hamish Hilarious because of course I tried typing `for inout` even though I knew it wouldn't compile. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 4, a compromise is to iterate over the indices of a mutable collection instead of the elements themselves, so that

```
for elem in mutableCollection {
    // `elem` is immutable ...
}
```

or

```
for var elem in mutableCollection {
   // `elem` is mutable, but a _copy_ of the collection element ...
}
```

becomes

```
for idx in mutableCollection.indices {
    // mutate `mutableCollection[idx]` ...
}
```

In your example:

```
for idx in f.columns.indices {
   f.columns[idx].cards.append(Card()) 
}
```

As @Hamish pointed out in the comments, a future version of Swift may implement a [mutating iteration](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#mutating-iteration), making

```
for inout elem in mutableCollection {
   // mutate `elem` ...
}
```

possible.