# Update/change array value of custom object- swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a custom `model` like bellow:

```
struct ContentModel {
    var id: Int64?
    var parentID: Int64?
    var subject: String?
    var langId: String?
    var isSelected: String?
    var identifier: String?
    var title: String?
    var count: Int64?
    var selectAll: String?
    var textSelectAll: String?
}
```

And:

```
struct SectionModel {
    var expand:Bool
    var title:String
    var content:[ContentModel]
}
```

How can I update a specific item from above model?

I am using from bellow code:

```
for resRoot in  displayListCourseFilter{
    for resSub in resRoot.content{
        if pId == resSub.parentID{
            resSub.selectAll = "true"
            resSub.isSelected = "true"
        }
    }
}
```

But say me:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'resSub' is a 'let' constant
```

NOTICE: All of my variables are `var`.

Comment: “All of my variables are var” No they are not. resSub and resRoot are let. And even if they were var they are still _copies_, so changing one won’t help you

Comment: Here is var displayListCourseFilter: [SectionModel] = [] and all of items are var, resolve my problem with response of Sh_Khan. Thank's a lot

Comment: That was also the answer in the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014345/how-do-people-deal-with-iterating-a-swift-struct-value-type-property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With struct

```
for i in displayListCourseFilter.indices {
   for j in displayListCourseFilter[i].content.indices  { 
        var item = displayListCourseFilter[i].content[j]
        if pId ==  item.parentID {
             item.selectAll = "true"
             item.isSelected = "true"
             displayListCourseFilter[i].content[j] = item
        }
    }
}
```

or make it a class and it will compile

Comment: @ Sh_Khan. Get me Cannot assign to property: 'resRoot' is a 'let' constant, yet.