# Swift: The Mysterious Case of the Vanishing Array Contents

Tags: swift

I have the following Swift code to extract the contents of an array of nested dictionaries decoded from JSON into an array of dictionaries I can use for a SwiftUI List view (i.e. Identifiable).  Anyway, that's why I'm doing this, the problem is much simpler, but very weird

```
struct Salespeople : Codable {
    let salespeople: [Salesperson]?
}

struct Territory: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: NSInteger
    let name: String
}

struct Salesperson : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: NSInteger
    let name: String
    let territories: [[String:Territory]]?
    var territoriesArray: [Territory]?
}

let salespeople = try! decoder.decode([[String:Salesperson]].self, from: dataResponse!)

var salespeopleArray:[Salesperson] = []

for salespersonDictionary in salespeople {
    var salesperson = salespersonDictionary["salesperson"]!
    salespeopleArray.append(salesperson)
    salesperson.territoriesArray = [Territory]()

    for territoryDictionary in salesperson.territories! {
        let territory = territoryDictionary["territory"]!
        salesperson.territoriesArray?.append(territory)
    } // <<<< Breakpoint here
}

dump(salespeopleArray)
```

The code loops through an array of salespeople, and for each of them, there is a nested loop to pull from the array of territories they may manage and build a derived territoriesArray - there's usually only one territory per salesperson, so the code only performs the nested loop once, but the code needs to cater for the possibility of more.

If I set a breakpoint at the end of each loop processing the territories, I can inspect and see that a territory has been appended to salesperson.territoriesArray as expected, which suggested the territoriesArray was initialised and appended to correctly. All Good.

```
Printing description of salesperson:
▿ Salesperson
  ▿ territories : Optional<Array<Dictionary<String, Territory>>>
    ▿ some : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 1 element
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : "territory"
          ▿ value : Territory
            - id : 801
            - name : "Yorkshire"
  ▿ territoriesArray : Optional<Array<Territory>>
    ▿ some : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : Territory
        - id : 801
        - name : "Yorkshire"
```

However, if I use the debugger to inspect the salespeopleArray on the next iteration (i.e. next salesperson), I can already see that the salesperson.territoriesArray value for the previous iteration (i.e. salesperson previously processed) has already been set to nil - the array built for the previous salesperson has vanished!

This continues until the completion on both loops, and when I dump the 'completed' salespersonArray, unsurprisingly (given what's been happening), territoriesArray for each and every salesperson is nil.

Extract from dump(salespeopleArray)

```
 ▿ myapp.Salesperson
    ▿ territories: Optional([["territory": myapp.Territory(id: 1572, name: "Suffolk")]])
      ▿ some: 1 element
        ▿ 1 key/value pair
          ▿ (2 elements)
            - key: "territory"
            ▿ value: myapp.Territory
              - id: 1572
              - name: "Suffolk"
    - territoriesArray: nil
```

Why are my territory entries vanishing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Because Array is a value type?

Comment: What’s the declaration for Salesperson?

Comment: Can't you replace `salesperson.territoriesArray` with a call to `map`/`compactMap` on  `salesperson.territories`?

Comment: @bg2b Thanks for reply.  I've added those to question (in first code extract).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for reply.  I tried that originally, but I couldn't get past the problem that the territories structure is an array of nested dictionaries with a root "territory:" from the original JSON - the very problem I was trying to fix with the map - hence the manual approach.  I'm new to Swift though, so maybe there's a way around that.

Comment: Closely related to, or even a duplicate of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014345/how-do-people-deal-with-iterating-a-swift-struct-value-type-property

Comment: @matt ...but how would I have known that if I didn't know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mysterious, it's a feature.

Swift Arrays and Dictionaries are value types. That means the line

```
var salesperson = salespersonDictionary["salesperson"]!
```

makes a **copy** of the `Salesperson` instance and assigns it to the variable `salesperson`. The changes you are going to make change the content of `salesperson` but **not** the value for key `salesperson` in `salespeople`.

A solution is to assign the modified `Salesperson` instance back to the array `salespeople`.

```
var salespeople = try! decoder.decode([[String:Salesperson]].self, from: dataResponse!)

var salespeopleArray:[Salesperson] = []

for (index, salespersonDictionary) in salespeople.enumerated() {
    var salesperson = salespersonDictionary["salesperson"]!
    salespeopleArray.append(salesperson)
    salesperson.territoriesArray = [Territory]()

    for territoryDictionary in salesperson.territories! {
        let territory = territoryDictionary["territory"]!
        salesperson.territoriesArray?.append(territory)
    } 
    salespeople[index] = salesperson
}
```

Comment: Slight correction to your [much appreciated] fixed code, is that the last statement needs to be salespeopleArray[index] = salesperson  Thanks again.